# Teradata and SQL Server : how to get hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, teradata, hierarchical-data, bteq

In Teradata/SQL Server, how to get by SQL/BTEQ the hierarchical top parent?

- Head teacher is minimum id among all the teacher of the student.
- if student 10 has 3 teachers 1,8,9; teacher (id) 8 & 9 are also students, and student 8 & 9 will have teacher 1/ i.e. minimum teaches same as 10 has

Say for following input, how can we get the desired output?

Input:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: Where are the rows with student 9, 7 and 1 coming from?

Comment: why is 3's head teacher 1? Your data makes very little sense, and it's not real hierarchy. Usually what you do is to create hierarchy for every row, might as well do it here and bin this design

Comment: check out the WITH RECURSIVE expression in Teradata. SQL Server should have the equivalent in CONNECT BY.